# Adding image to ListBox item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I am currently working on a C# WPF appplication where I am trying to add an image, followed by some text in each list item.

I've got the binding working for the text but the image isn't displayed.

Below is my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ServerAdministrator.FtpDirectoryListing"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ServerAdministrator"
        Title="FTP Directory Listing" Height="391" Width="599">
    <Grid>
        <StatusBar Height="30" Margin="0,322,0,0" Name="statusBar1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <ToolBar Height="26" Name="toolBar1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,32,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="517" />
        <ListBox x:Name="lstDirecotryListing" Height="233" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,61,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="553">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DirectoryListing}">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Margin="3" Text="{Binding path}" />
                        <ContentControl Margin="3" Content="{Binding image}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Below is my DirectoryListing class

```
class DirectoryListing
    {
        public string path {get; set;}
        public Image image{get; set;}
        public DirectoryListing(Image imgage, String path)
        {
            this.image = image;
            this.path = path;
        }
    }
```

Below is how I am adding items to the listbox

```
Image image = new Image();
            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ServerAdministrator\ServerAdministrator\bin\Debug\images\directory.png"));
            image.Source = bi;
            lstDirecotryListing.Items.Add(new DirectoryListing(image, "hello"));
```

The text is getting added fine but not the image.

I'm not sure if it is related but I get the following in the Console Output in VS2010

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with
>   reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor,
>   AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl',
>   AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=HorizontalContentAlignment;
>   DataItem=null; target element is 'ComboBoxItem' (Name=''); target
>   property is 'HorizontalContentAlignment' (type 'HorizontalAlignment')
>   System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with
>   reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor,
>   AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl',
>   AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=VerticalContentAlignment;
>   DataItem=null; target element is 'ComboBoxItem' (Name=''); target
>   property is 'VerticalContentAlignment' (type 'VerticalAlignment')

Thanks for any help you can provide

**UPDATE**

I've got it working thanks to Clemens answer, still using the same two variables as the path isn't the path to the image, but anyway, it is displaying the image and text now.

The problem is it displays the text and the picture is underneath, I need to show the picture and the text side by side, how can I do this?

Comment: The exception is for HorizontalContentAlignment on a combo box item, not likely related to this problem. Your code looks fine, I'll look some more and I hope you get an answer!

Comment: Can you post the `XAML` where the `ComboBoxItem` is defined

Comment: I've looked again. that message about the combo box, is for a previous dialogue, not the one with the issue

Comment: You should not have a ContentControl with a Content property bound to an Image control in your view model. Instead there should be an Image control in the DataTemplate, which has its `Source` property bound to either a (file name) string or a BitmapImage property in the view model.

Comment: I've tried that as well, does the same thing, assuming I'm doing it correctly

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Reduce your view model to this:

```
public class DirectoryListing
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

and change your DataTemplate to this:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Margin="3" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            <Image Margin="3" Source="{Binding Path}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Built-in type conversion will automatically create an ImageSource from the file path string.

Comment: Thanks this has worked, there is a second problem, I've updated my question

Comment: Set `Orientation="Horizontal"` on the StackPanel.

Comment: Thanks as simple as that. Thanks for your help much appreciated